# Can we put regular expression for a value in a DTD?

Tags: regex, xml, dtd

I would like to know if there is a way to associate regular expression for the value of an attribute.
like in XML Schema:

```
 <xs:pattern value="([0-9]|[A-Z]){3}" />
```

to make the DTD match with this XML line:

```
<airport iata="LAE" name="Nadzab Airport" city="Nadzab" country="Papua New Guinea">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, DTDs do not support regex.  Use XSD for vastly superior datatyping.

DTD attribute values can be enumerations, however:

```
<!ELEMENT airport EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST airport iata (LAE|LAX|LGA) #IMPLIED>
```