# XML Element is not matching the DTD

Tags: xml, dtd

Consider the following snippet -

> ## DTD

```
<!DOCTYPE hotels_list [
    <!ELEMENT hotels_list ( hotel+ ) >
    <!ELEMENT hotel ( id, name, stars, Facilities, Address, distance_from_center, available ) >
    <!ELEMENT id ( #PCDATA ) >
    <!ELEMENT name ( #PCDATA ) >
    <!ELEMENT stars ( #PCDATA ) >
    <!ELEMENT Address ( #PCDATA ) >
    <!-- Facilities only contains at least one of the options in (internet,gym,restaurant,parking,pickup -->
    <!ELEMENT Facilities (Internet*,Gym*,Restaurant*,Parking*,Pickup*) >
    <!ELEMENT available ( #PCDATA ) >
    <!ELEMENT distance_from_center ( #PCDATA ) >
    ]>
```

> ## XML Code

```
<hotels_list>
    <hotel>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Les Jardins Du Marais</name>
        <stars>3</stars>
        <Facilities>Internet</Facilities>
        <Address>74 rue Amelot, Paris, 75011</Address>
        <distance_from_center>2</distance_from_center>
        <available>True</available>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Golden Tulip Little Palace</name>
        <stars>4</stars>
        <Facilities>Internet,Gym,Parking,Restaurant</Facilities>
        <Address>4 rue Salomon
        De Caus, Paris 75003</Address>
        <distance_from_center>0.1</distance_from_center>
        <available>False</available>
    </hotel>
</hotels_list>
```

But the facilities shows error as

```
The content of element type "Facilities" must match "(Internet*,Gym*,Restaurant*,Parking*,Pickup*)".xml(MSG_CONTENT_INVALID)
```

Am I missing something here ,  can someone please help?

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Facilities` is a list of elements and not a regular expression for text content.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hotels_list [
    <!ELEMENT hotels_list (hotel+)>
    <!ELEMENT hotel (id, name, stars, Facilities, Address, distance_from_center, available)>
    <!ELEMENT id (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT stars (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Address (#PCDATA)>
    <!-- Facilities only contains at least one of the options in (internet,gym,restaurant,parking,pickup -->
    <!ELEMENT Facilities (Internet*, Gym*, Restaurant*, Parking*, Pickup*)>
    <!ELEMENT Internet (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Gym (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Restaurant (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Parking (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT Pickup (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT available (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT distance_from_center (#PCDATA)>
]>
<hotels_list>
    <hotel>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Les Jardins Du Marais</name>
        <stars>3</stars>
        <Facilities><Internet/></Facilities>
        <Address>74 rue Amelot, Paris, 75011</Address>
        <distance_from_center>2</distance_from_center>
        <available>True</available>
    </hotel>
    <hotel>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>Golden Tulip Little Palace</name>
        <stars>4</stars>
        <Facilities><Internet/><Gym/><Restaurant/><Parking/></Facilities>
        <Address>4 rue Salomon
        De Caus, Paris 75003</Address>
        <distance_from_center>0.1</distance_from_center>
        <available>False</available>
    </hotel>
</hotels_list>
```

Comment: But I need Internet, gym, restaurant ... as values not tags

Comment: Probably no chance with DTD. Write a XSD schema. In a schema you can use regular expression patterns: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819370/regular-expression-pattern-matching-in-xsd

Comment: @AashishPawar You may try attribute value enumerations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49175355/can-we-put-regular-expression-for-a-value-in-a-dtd

Comment: but how ? if you have any working code snippet  then please let me know or post it as answer