# Can I use regular expressions in DTD schemas?

Tags: regex, xml, schema, dtd

I want to enforce that an XML element has to contain an ISBN code. Therefore, I need your typical pattern "[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}......".

Could that be achieved in a DTD schema? I've read you can't combine a DTD with regular expressions, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: You can switch to XML Schema (XSD) for that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49175355/14419

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't define regex patterns with DTD.

You can enforce [regex patterns with XSD schemas](https://www.regular-expressions.info/xml.html).

```
<xsd:simpleType name="SSN">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:token">
        <xsd:pattern value="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Another option is applying some sort of other validation, such as [Schematron](https://www.schematron.com).

Comment: Ideally of course you would also validate the ISBN's check digit. That's a bit more challenging, even in Schematron.